# find selection number and loop in ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a list of numbers in a row. I want to select the first number, find the number in the other word document, and copy second number and find the second number in the document then move to next number and continue searching.

```
Selection.Copy
Windows("zoology- repeaters [Compatibility Mode]").Activate
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "2"
    .Replacement.Text = Selection.Characters
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
Windows("FINAL QP").Activate
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
Windows("01 [Compatibility Mode]").Activate
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
Selection.Copy
Windows("zoology- repeaters [Compatibility Mode]").Activate
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a macro which automatically copies the question number from doc - A and searches the question number in doc - B, copies the question and pastes the question in doc-C

Comment: If that's all you want to know, then the Answer is Yes!. It is possible.

Comment: @mikku Actually I've tried using macros. I've done changes to my vba code and I understood how it works. I only want how to copy paste in find and proceed search. TQ

Comment: Post the code that you have tried, and point where you are facing issues.

Comment: @Mikku at '.Text = "2" ', I have a list of numbers. But the code only selects 2 question from the doc-B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste the copied number in Find dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395627/paste-the-copied-number-in-find-dialog-box)